# How can I wait for only one of three events (mouse input, keyboard input, or WinWaitClose) in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

In my scenario, either a window will close automatically, or the user will provide an input via mouse or keyboard.

If the window closes automatically, I want to open a PDF. This is easy:

```
WinWaitClose, ahk_id %cmdHwnd%
Run, "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "%path%\cv.pdf"
```

But if the window *doesn't* close automatically (*i.e.* the PDF failed to compile), then the user's going to close that window manually, *e.g.* hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the close button. In this case, I do *not* want the above `WinWaitClose` to trigger!

So another way of putting my question is, how do I "cancel" a `WinWaitClose` listener upon mouse or keyboard input?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could rely on the Seconds timer in `WinWaitClose`, and if that fails, you can rely on the ErrorLevel which will be set to 1.

```
; Set WinWaitTimer to wait 2 seconds before timing out.
WinWaitClose, ahk_id %cmdHwnd%,, 2
if (ErrorLevel) {
    ; Do something.
}
else
{
    Run, "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "%path%\cv.pdf"
}
```